# Can't install 12.04 with S3 Savage

Tags: 12.04, installation, video

I can't install 12.04.2 from CD because the video is corrupt. I have an S3 pro Savage4 video card and a LCD display. After booting, the top half of the screen sort of appears but is really unreadable. Moving the cursor around sort of helps, but not well enough to make it readable.

Since I'm trying to install from a CD, there is no way to modify anything on it. (The advice given to fix a running system can't be used.) I have 11.10 currently installed but the last time I tried to upgrade it the network adapter driver didn't work, so I had to revert back to 11.10. I don't want to just try the upgrade again because I want to make sure **all** the drivers are working first.

Is there another 12.04 installation image planned? Is there a way to get past this problem using a CD install?

Comment: I have been having same issue, i tested a 12.04 (initial release) CD and it worked. seems like an issue with kernel or xorg update/changes I have tried all new releases, upto from 12.04.1 to 13.10 non of them worked,

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting `nomodeset` and/or `acpi=off` in the CD boot menu. See this guide: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

UPDATE: There are a couple of more options you can try: `xmodule=savage` `xmodule=vesa` `xmodule=svga` `norandr` `nodrm` `nocomposite` `no3d` `noddc`

Add them to the kernel command line manually in various combinations, plain vga should work if the card isn't faulty.

Comment: I tried each individually and both together, it didn't work. I added vga=771 (800x600) to the boot line, that didn't help either. The same corrupted screen always appeared.

Comment: Thanks for the additional UPDATE options to try, but they didn't work either. There is no problem with the card because it works in 11.10. The problem always occurs after about 5 minutes into the boot when it switches over into the full screen desktop. The top half of the screen is somewhat readable, but the bottom half is completely bolluxed, with 8 vertical sections. This end result does not change no matter what options are tried.